# Cocos2d game termination problem when a moving sprite goes inside the bounding box of a animating still sprite(a ball get into a hole)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, termination

Let me explain it in  depth, when ever `if(CGRectContainsPoint([hole1 boundingBox], ball1.position))` condition goes true, i do lots of stuffs, like unscheduled, a selector, destroying a ball body calling an animation (**please refer Code below**)etc. This work properly most of the time. But sometimes when ball is really near to hole(just touching the hole but but not enough to make the above condition true), or is been throws towards the hole really fast speed, then application got terminated. I have checked, by commenting many actions which are been performed in this section, but got nothing helpful, application keep terminating when some efforts are been done to make it terminate.

```
if(CGRectContainsPoint([hole1 boundingBox], ball1.position))
{
    ballBody->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(0.0f,0.0f));
    ballBody->SetAngularVelocity(0.0f);

    [self unschedule:@selector(tick:)];
    self.isTouchEnabled = NO;

    [self removeChild:ball1 cleanup:YES];
    world->DestroyBody(ballBody);

    // create the sprite sheet
    CCSpriteSheet *spriteSheet;

    GolfBallsAppDelegate *appDelegate = (GolfBallsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if([appDelegate.ballValue isEqualToString:@"cricketball"])
    {
        spriteSheet = [CCSpriteSheet spriteSheetWithFile:@"cricket_ball_strip.png"];
    }
    else if([appDelegate.ballValue isEqualToString:@"ironball"])
    {
        spriteSheet = [CCSpriteSheet spriteSheetWithFile:@"iron_ball_strip.png"];
    }
    else if([appDelegate.ballValue isEqualToString:@"golfball"])
    {
        spriteSheet = [CCSpriteSheet spriteSheetWithFile:@"golf_ball_strip.png"];
    }
    else if([appDelegate.ballValue isEqualToString:@"soccerball"])
    {
        spriteSheet = [CCSpriteSheet spriteSheetWithFile:@"soccer_ball_strip.png"];
    }
    else if([appDelegate.ballValue isEqualToString:@"basketball"])
    {
        spriteSheet = [CCSpriteSheet spriteSheetWithFile:@"basket_ball_strip.png"];
    }

    spriteSheet.position = ccp(hole1.position.x,60);
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];

    float frameWidth = 96;
    float frameHeight = 84;

    CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:spriteSheet.texture rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight)];

    [spriteSheet addChild:sprite];

    //if(animation)
    {
        // create the animation
        CCAnimation *spriteAnimation = [CCAnimation animationWithName:@"potting" delay:0.1f];

        int frameCount = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) 
        {
            // create an animation frame
            CCSpriteFrame *frame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:spriteSheet.texture rect:CGRectMake(x*frameWidth,0*frameHeight,frameWidth,frameHeight) offset:ccp(0,0)];
            [spriteAnimation addFrame:frame];

            frameCount++;

            // stop looping after we've added 14 frames
            if (frameCount == 6)
            {
                //[self removeChild:spriteSheet cleanup:YES];
                break;
            }
        }

        // create the action
        CCAnimate *spriteAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:spriteAnimation];
        //CCRepeatForever *repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:spriteAction];

        // run the action
        [sprite runAction:spriteAction];
        //[sprite runAction:repeat];
    }
    [self schedule:@selector(loading) interval:0.5];
    [self schedule:@selector(holeFinish) interval:1];
    //[self removeChild:spriteSheet cleanup:YES];
}
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT:** What i found is, problem with folling lines `[self removeChild:ball1 cleanup:YES];
    world->DestroyBody(ballBody);`
 (MAY be). but as it not occurs always, (as I mentioned), thus it's being ridiculous.

Comment: I recommend you set it up so you can repeat the same movement of the ball exactly so that it crashes every time, then start to comment out parts of code. This will at least give you the point where it crashes, otherwise it's pretty hard to guess what's going on.

Comment: oh yes i did it, but it didn't helped, actually  when ball is thrown, fast then this problem occors.

Comment: so, when the problem occurs, what is the crash log/stack trace message

Comment: Well, that sure is a problem :) I am not familiar with cocos2d so I can't comment on that, but you will need to narrow the problem down more, or preferably get a stack trace, otherwise it's really hard for anyone to guess what's happening.

Comment: yeah that's true I'm trying ma best to resolve it, and the only solution i got is to comment complete code(lol), so what i found is, problem with folling lines `[self removeChild:ball1 cleanup:YES];
    world->DestroyBody(ballBody);
` (MAY be). but as it not occurs always, (as I mentioned), thus it's being ridiculous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem will be that you are trying to delete a body when the b2World is 'locked', (When the world is busy working out collisions).

Try flagging the object as ready for deletion, and deleting it at the start of your next loop:

Replace:

```
[self removeChild:ball1 cleanup:YES];
world->DestroyBody(ballBody);
```

with

```
ball1.isDead = YES;
```

And at the start of your next game loop:

```
for (Ball b in balls)
{
    if (b.isDead)
        world->DestroyBody(b.ballBody);
}
```

Comment: But as you can see i use a animation of potting the ball, so i think it'll look bad if i don't remove ball. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you don't remove the ball, just don't remove it in the same frame. Remove it at the start of the next frame when the world isn't locked. At 60 fps, that's only 0.016 seconds later

Comment: what if i don't destroy the ball?